# Can I enable hardware acceleration for Angular Material?

Tags: angularjs, hardware-acceleration, angular-material

The current version does not seem smooth and fast. Even a simple app lags on a general phone (except the iPhone).

Is that because the hardware acceleration is not enabled? Or just that the hardware of the phones are not good enough?

If I want hardware acceleration, do I have to edit the sources?

Comment: On Chrome by default, CSS transitions and effects are rendered by the GPU. While I can't answer if you can or cannot enable hardware acceleration on the JavaScript side of Material Design, I do think the lagging issue might be because of poor hardware. Material Design is part of Android 5.0, which pushes up minimum system requirements a little bit. Most of applications that got updated to Material Design and run on phones which didn't get the Lollipop upgrade because of their hardware, seem to run slower, plus adding up the browser layer to a non-native app can really make the page run slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is not with angular-material, you need to check your code.

Talking about hardware acceleration, you can force hardware acceleration with help of css.

Add this css class to body

```
.accelerate {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 }
```

Read more about hardware acceleration [hardware acceleration on smashing magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/21/play-with-hardware-accelerated-css/)